# disable code completion if typescript is not ready

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Sometimes I do code completion and don't realize that typescript is not yet ready. Then I mistake the results (which are I guess a collection of all functions calls VSE finds in that file) for real members of the given type. I know that there is a cube symbol before the function when it's really a member of that type. However, I tend to overlook it.

Is there some way to disable code completion if typescript is not ready?

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

`"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,`
in `.vscode/settings.json`

see [options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense)